# How to model a Patricia-Trie graph

Tags: java, graph

I am trying to implement insert method for  the Patricia Trie data structure. So if I insert the string `aba` then the string  `abc` I will get the following trie in the screen shot as a result.
[image]

I have tried this code but I do not know how to model the graph as Output and how can I create many nodes as needed without using node1, node2, node3, etc?

**Particia class:**

```
package patriciaTrie;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Patricia {

    private Node root;
    private Node parent;
    private Node node1;
    private Node node2;

    // create a new node
    public Patricia() {
        root = null;
        parent = null;
    }

    // inserts a string into the trie
    public void insert(String s) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(s, "o-");
            parent = new Node("-o");
        } else {
            insert(root, s);
        }

    }

    private void insert(Node root, String s) {
        int len1 = root.edge.length();
        int len2 = s.length();
        int len = Math.min(len1, len2);
        for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
            if (s.charAt(index) != root.edge.charAt(index)) {

                // In case the string are not equal, then split them.
                String samesubString = s.substring(0, index);

                String substringSplit1 = root.edge.substring(index);
                String substringSplit2 = s.substring(index);

                 root.edge = samesubString;
                 node1 = new Node(substringSplit1, "-o");
                 node2 =  new Node(substringSplit2, "-o");

                System.out.println(root.value + root.edge + node1.value +node1.edge + node2.value + node2.edge);

            } else {
                System.out.println("They are the same - " + index);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Patricia p = new Patricia();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String op = s.next();
            if (op.equals("INSERT")) {
                p.insert(s.next());
            } 

        }

    }

}
```

**Node class:**

```
package patriciaTrie;

public class Node {

    String edge;
    String value;


    Node(String edge, String value) {
        this.edge = edge;
        this.value = value;
    }

    Node(String value){
        this.value = value;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array or list of follower edges, instead of only one edge.
It is usual in graphs to use a list of follower edges, this is nothing special for a trie.

To build up the Patricia trie use a Node class simillar to:

```
public class TrieNode {
    String value;
    // The outgoing (downstream) neighbour nodes
    List<TrieNode> next; // probably LinkedList

    /** Default Constructor with value */
    public TrieNode(String value) {
       this.value = value
    }
}
```

and once it is build up, you may convert to a read-only graph, using less memory (tries are often used for dictionaries that do not change anymore at runtime)

to finally have a low memory consumption trie, its uses array instead of an List. A List always uses more memory than an array.

```
public class TrieNode {
    String value;
    TrieNode[] next;
}
```

In your example you can build the graph:

```
TrieNode nodeRoot = new TrieNode ("ab");
TrieNode nodeLeft = new TrieNode ("a");
TrieNode nodeRight = new TrieNode ("c");
nodeRoot.next.add(nodeLeft);
nodeRoot.next.add(nodeRight);
```

Comment: please comment your downvote

Comment: I do not know  who downvoted it.

Comment: Ok the code was wrong, the downvote was ok, but it should have been commented, who ever voted. Now it is correct. A Node has many followers; in fact the Node represents the edge, It is a EdgeNode

Comment: fixed another bug: now "next" is more descriptive, that are the outgoing edges

Comment: I do not need the node class!?

Comment: You do not need both: node and edges, this onyl for drawing on a paper, It is a NodeEdge which represent the value (String) and the followers

Comment: Thanks for your Explanation but do I need the constructor with  the value Parameter ?`EdgeNode (String edge, String value) {this.next = edge;this.value = value;}`

Comment: No you have multiple followers "next" not only one:. And at time of construction of an TrieNode the followers are not yet know. So you construct an TrieNode with empty "next". You have to set it later and insert, by getting next: TrieNode.getNext().add(new TrieNode("a");

Comment: Please look at the example with 5 lines. That builds up your graph.